# Maximum child objects React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Was wondering how many child objects an object can have in react native.
I mean as in both direct and children of children e.c.t.

I'm aware that the JavaScript spec says it is infinite (bar memory restrictions) but also that most browsers enforce a limit.

Thanks, Ed.